# How to animate expande and collapse with AnimatedVisibility in Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row with three items, and depending on the option selected, it shows or hide these items:

[image]

When I select another option in the dropdown menu, these three items change and should show only two o just one item, like this:

[image]

The items should resize and make an animation when resizing.

For that, I have created three different buttons inside a Row, and each button has a width of 1, and each button is inside an AnimatedVisibility, but the animation is the following

[image]

The code is :

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp)
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = modifier,
            onClick = { onClick() },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = white),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = text).uppercase(),
                color = if (isSelected) black else pink,
                style = Typography.body2,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), visible = viewModel.state.rentOptionVisibility
        ) {
            Button(
                modifier = modifier,
                onClick = { onClick() },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = white),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = text).uppercase(),
                    style = Typography.body2,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            visible = viewModel.state.newConstructionOptionVisibility
        ) {
            Button(
                modifier = modifier,
                onClick = { onClick() },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = white),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = text).uppercase(),
                    style = Typography.body2,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

A is always visible, that's why is not inside an `AnimatedVisibility` component.